# How can I create a loop that will give me lists with names in increasing numerical order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a code that will give me

```
bin1= []
bin2= []
...
...
bin(Numbins)= []
```

Here is my attempt:

so earlier in my code I created lists PriceDiffList and DataList.
Here is the part of the code I am having trouble with

```
Numbins = (1/4)* len(DataList)

print(Numbins)

a1 = Numbins % len(PriceDiffList)

print(a1)

for i in range(1, a1):

    for 'n' in range (1, numbins):

        bin'n' = PriceDiffList[[(i-1)*Numbins] : [i*Numbins]]

        bin'n + 1' = bin'n'

        print (bin'n')
```

But this does not work. Here is the error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-16-1c0c8c3e71aa>", line 41
    bin'n' = PriceDiffList[[(i-1)*Numbins] : [i*Numbins]]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any other ideas? I could potentially use zip, or append but I'm not exactly sure how to properly write this out.

Comment: Post code as text, not as an image. Also, explain what "does not work" means.

Comment: So, where's your attempt? Why do you want variables of the form `xxx1`, `xxx2`, etc? That's always a bad idea. Instead, you should have just a list `xxx_list`, where `xxx1` is equivalent to `xxx_list[0]`.

Comment: look, I'm fairly new to python and self taught. If you could please help me get an answer that lets me have lists with those names, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `bin'n + 1'` is not a valid python synthax

Comment: I have added the code and added the error message

Comment: @dgan yes I know, so how do I fix it? Like I said I'm fairly new to python and Im not sure how to go about this

Comment: So, it looks like you are trying to treat variables like data. Some scripting languages actually allow this, but it isn't in Python (and is usually a bad approach, it leads to hard to reason-about code). Instead, it sounds like you want to use a *list* (since, you want to group a bunch of objects indexed by increasing integers).

Comment: Also, it would be really helpful if you gave some example inputs with expected outputs. I think I know what you are trying to do, but it would be a lot more clear (and your questions will be better received) if you provide example input and expected output.

Comment: Why do you want to do this and not use a list named `bin` instead? You already know how to use lists since you have `DataList` and `PriceDiffList`.

Comment: I’m using bin my list name because it goes with the mathematical calculations that this code does, sorry for my confusion if bin means something else in python but I just want it as my list name for reasons that are important later on in the code and future calculations

Comment: `bin` is a built-in function. You could just call it `priceBin` or something. But you say "using bin as my list name" - you're not using it as a list. Why not do that? `priceBin[0]`, `priceBin[1]` - instead of `bin1`, `bin2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the variable names like that, you have to use `exec` and `eval`. However, I would advise against this because **`eval` is evil**:

```
for n in range (1, numbins):
    exec('bin'+str(n)+' = PriceDiffList[[(i-1)*Numbins] : [i*Numbins]]')
    exec('bin'+str(n + 1)+' = bin'+str(n))
    print eval('bin'+str(n))
```

Comment: I am getting this as am error message:  File "<ipython-input-17-5e773e9d0791>", line 40
    print eval('bin'+str(n))
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax Where the arrow is pointing to eval. Is there anything I have to import to be able to use eval?

Comment: @StephSmelewski no, (although you *really shouldn't use `eval` for this anyway), you are likely just missing a closing parentheses somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

this should help..

```
from collections import  defaultdict
some_dict=defaultdict(list)

    for n in range (1, numbins):
        some_d["bin"+str(n)] = PriceDiffList[[(i-1)*Numbins] : [i*Numbins]]

        some_d["bin"+str(n+1)]= some_d["bin"+str(n)]

    print (some_d["bin"+str(n)])
```

Comment: I am getting this as an error message: TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `some_dict=defaultdict(list)`, not `some_dict=defaultdict[list]`